# How do I define a list of constants in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, constants

When we want to define one constant like pi, we can do it like `public static final float pi = 3.14`. But lets say I want to have a list of stopwords which gets produced after scanning a file which also changes. Can I also do a "lazy" initialization? how would you do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "But lets say I want to have a list of stopwords which gets produced after scanning a file which also changes"

Comment: Sounds like you want a factory class that will produce a class containing a list of constants.

Comment: @Lokesh I am scanning a file and storing the words in a list. But I dont want to store high-freq words like "a", "is" etc. So I keep them in a file. But I can later add to this list. So i want to have a list of words as constants but this will be produced after scanning the file. Or is it a bad idea to call the list of words a constant?

Comment: As it isn't constant: probably. Constants in Java (i.e. `static final` fields) are for atomic, unchangeable stuff. Their value even is inlined by the compiler so you would need to recompile every dependency that uses any public constant. The `List` itself (but not its content!) could be regarded a constant but their are much better ways to publish its value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a **static nested class** initializing your constants.

Advantage of this: This **static nested class** would be loaded only when you use it even if you already used the wrapping class.

You would just "scan" your file containing stopwords in the nested class's constructor and assign them to your constants variables, themselves contained into the nested class.

Note: I hate using **static initializer** when dealing with "complex" code like scanning some files.. this would mask the potential thrown exceptions (during development) since an `ExceptionInInitializerError` would be thrown instead..frustrating ;)   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you describe does not match to the Java constant variables. Your constants are data.

You can use a map (`HashMap<String>`) and initialize it with the values of the high-freq words.
Then as you read the words from the file/text/scanner, you check if the word is in the map and decide what to do.